# Python 3.5 searching for libpython3.6m.so.1.0

Tags: docker, python-3.5, gitlab-ci

I have a docker image based from python:3.5-slim, that I added Oracle 12 on it, so my tests on GitLab can run in it.

When GitLab start building the environment, like doing the pip install, I get this error message:

"/builds/root/ppc_busca/venv/bin/python3: error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.6m.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

The thing is, how can it complains about the file 'libpython3.6m' if my python version is 3.5? That is something that I don't understand.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What Python libraries do you have installed? Are any of those using natively-compiled extensions? If so, what are those extensions compiled against?

Comment: Say, you installed `cxOracle`, a Python library that uses a compiled extension. It comes with a `.so` file that Python loads, and it'll be compiled against *a* `libpython3.x` version. If you installed the 3.6 version into your 3.5 Python setup, you'll find it won't work.